# How to protect a NodeJS API server used with a React application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a React front-end that calls REST APIs. The front-end and back-end are hosted on different servers. It's a simple application so I don't want to implement User accounts/API keys. How do I secure the backend so that it could be only used by my React front-end.

Comment: Change ur firewall settings in the server node so that it only accept request from ur front end server.

Comment: I'm using Heroku to host the front-end and the back-end. I'm pretty sure Heroku will not give me a static IP for my instances. Can't use a firewall if the IP address keeps on changing.

Comment: authentication. but nothing will stop a user from using said authentication outside of your app.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot, the only way that I see could come close is by generating a token that's embedded in one of your static React files and validate that token upon request (for every instance downloaded by a user), but it would be impossible to prevent an attacker from fetching that file/token and call the backend APIs with it. The only way to protect a backend is via user login/2-legged OAuth.